# What are asp .net validators rendered into in HTML?

Tags: asp.net, tags, validation, html

Are all asp net validators rendered as < span> tags?

This is important as spans are being used in the styling and a strict css heiracrchy is in place and I don't want to add redundant < span> tags around what will be rendered at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use ASP.NET more than just the validators are wrapped with spans. A RadioButtonList also has a span wrapped around the items. Very annoying sometimes.

Comment: That would include Label.'s as well.